# Заменить условие if

Tags: javascript, функции

Есть две кнопки. Если нажать на первую кнопку, то появится 3-я кнопка, по клику на которую должен появится новый контент. У меня не выходит каким-то образом заменить условие if в проверке на null и в целом реализовать как-то не через условные операторы.

```js
let click1 = document.getElementById("click1");
      let click2 = document.getElementById("click2");
      let content = document.getElementById("content");

      const inf = {
        click1: '<button id="click3">Click3</button>',
        click2: "click2"
      };

      function afterClick(newContent) {
        content.innerHTML = inf[newContent];
        let click3 = document.getElementById("click3");
        thirdClick(click3);
      }

      click1.addEventListener("click", function() {
        afterClick("click1");
      });
      click2.addEventListener("click", function() {
        afterClick("click2");
      });

      function thirdClick(newClick) {
        if (newClick !== null) {
          newClick.addEventListener("click", function() {
            inf.click1 += "Click3";
            afterClick("click1");
          });
        }
      }
```

```html
    <button id="click1">Click1</button>
    <button id="click2">Click2</button>
    <div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: А где у вас `if` и проверка на `null`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov в функции thirdClick

Comment: А чем она вам мешает?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov мне абсолютно ничем не мешает. По заданию так надо сделать

Comment: А вы точно задание поняли? Проверка того, что у вас функция `document.getElementById()` возвращает не `null` является абсолютно нормальной

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может вам такой вариант подойдет:

```
function thirdClick(newClick) {
    try {
      newClick.addEventListener("click", function() {
        inf.click1 += "Click3";
        afterClick("click1");
      });
    } catch (err) {
      //что делать с ошибкой? Например, почистить контент
      content.innerText = ''
    }
```